# jQuery validate not accepting my form element names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that users fill up to before uploading into my database.The form lets users upload up to 3 images and i would like to make the user upload at least ONE image, so i would like to make it required.However, i can't seem to make it work with jQUery's validate plugin as the names of the file inputs are lumped together in an array.

My jQuery Code (Extract):

```
$('#BizAddItem').validate({

    errorElement:"span",
    errorPlacement:function(error,element){

        $(error).insertAfter(element);

    },

    rules:{

        //More items validated here

        BizAddItemFiles[]:{

            required:true
        },

    messages:{

        //More items here

        BizAddItemFiles[]:{

            required:"Please upload a file"
        },

    },

    },

    submitHandler:function(form){

    form.submit();

    }

});
```

My HTML (Extract):

```
//More items above
            <div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
                <label for='BizAddItemFile1'>Upload Image[DP]</label>
                <input type='file' id='BizAddItemFile1' name='BizAddItemFiles[]' />
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
                <label for='BizAddItemFile2'>Upload Image</label>
                <input type='file' id='BizAddItemFile2' name='BizAddItemFiles[]' />
                <span></span>
            </div>

            <div class='BizAddItemDetails'>
                <label for='BizAddItemFile3'>Upload Image</label>
                <input type='file' id='BizAddItemFile3' name='BizAddItemFiles[]' />
                <span></span>
            </div>

//More items below
```

jQuery is giving me an error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

due to the square brackets, but how would i make it validate my file uploads then if the names are not being accepted by jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 rules:{

        //More items validated here

        'BizAddItemFiles[]':{

            required:true
        },

    messages:{

        //More items here

        'BizAddItemFiles[]':{

            required:"Please upload a file"
        },
```